# A fatal error occurred while performing the refactoring: Force.com IDE does not support deleting resource

Tags: lightning-aura-components, force.com-ide

I'm using eclipse with my Salesforce developer edition. And I can no longer save my component to the server because I have a test.js file in my component folder.

If I try to delete it I get the fatal error message:

> A fatal error occurred while performing the refactoring: Force.com IDE does not support deleting resource

How do I get rid of the test.js file that blocks me from saving to server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I found out how to delete it!

I had to disable sever communication (Work Offline from the Force.com's contextual Project Explorer menu) in order to be able to delete the `test.js` file.

Comment: Nice finding. I was also facing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

is `test.js` included in your package.xml file? If not it won't get deployed/saved to the server. If it is, you can manually remove it from package.xml, and just delete (or not) the local copy.

Comment: No it's not in the package.xml and still unable to delete it!